# Add a local dependency to a Play project

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies, playframework-2.2

I have a few compiled *.jar files. I want to add them as the dependencies and be able to use on the hosting later.

What directory do I put those *.jar files and how do I add them to the project to be able to use their classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put them in "lib" folder in the root of your project.

Comment: are you sure? That's play 2.2 and there is not such a folder by default.

Comment: as i remember in any version you should create folder by yourself if not exists